# Taking the derivative of an integral $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\frac{1}{g(x)}}^{+\infty} \theta f(\theta) d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to get the following derviative. $f(\theta$) is a density function.  $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\frac{1}{g(x)}}^{+\infty} \theta f(\theta) d\theta$$

I believe that the answer should be

$$ \frac{1}{g(x)}f\left(\frac{1}{g(x)}\right)\frac{1}{g(x)^2}g'(x)$$

Am I correct?

This is a small part of a larger problem in a paper. I can't reproduce the author's result to the larger problem, so I am trying to figure out where I might be going wrong.

Comment: You cannot assume the integral is defined at all, let alone differentiable. Making the upper limit some constant would be OK, and the derivative would be independent of the constant, but you can't use $\infty$ that way without quite strong constraints on the function $f$. That said, I agree with your result.

Comment: Thanks Peter. From previous arguments, we do know that the integral is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there are some requirements on the convergence of the integral and on the functions involved for this to be even possible. But let's suppose we have the appropriate conditions. Now let's define

$$\alpha(x)=\int_x^\infty\theta f(\theta)~\mathrm{d}\theta$$

and

$$\beta(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}.$$

We now want to compute

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\alpha(\beta(x))=\alpha'(\beta(x))\beta'(x).$$

Now using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that

$$\alpha'(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_x^\infty\theta f(\theta)~\mathrm{d}\theta=-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_\infty^x\theta f(\theta)~\mathrm{d}\theta=-xf(x).$$

Furthermore

$$\beta'(x)=-\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)^2}.$$

Combining this we find that

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{\frac{1}{g(x)}}^\infty\theta f(\theta)~\mathrm{d}\theta=\left(-\frac{1}{g(x)}f\left(\frac{1}{g(x)}\right)\right)\cdot\left(-\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)^2}\right)=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)^3}f\left(\frac{1}{g(x)}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks Lorago. From previous arguments we know that this integral is finite. Do we need anything else to get the result?

Comment: @serwaah is the integral a Riemann or Lebesgue integral?

Comment: I think it's a Riemann integral. It's the expectation of a well-defined distribution and elsewhere we show that the expectation exists and is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> If $f$ satisfies all convergences constraints required, consider $\varphi(x)=\displaystyle\int_x^\infty\theta f(\theta)d\theta$ and $\psi(x)=\varphi\left(\dfrac1{g(x)}\right)$ then use chain rule.